# Can we query tables from different DB servers in a single query in Python application. Ex. Between oracle and postgres connection

Tags: python, database, postgresql, oracle, web-applications

I need to query tables from different DB running on different servers i.e. Oracle and PostgreSQL.

I have found that tables from different database can be queried by giving fully qualified names. Is it possible to query tables from different database servers

Comment: Yes, you can query tables separately from each connection. If you are asking if you can create a query that combines tables from each connection in a single query, then no. To do that I would suggest using a `Foreign Data Wrapper(FDW` in Postgres that points at the Oracle database. See [Oracle FDW](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - _"suggest using a Foreign Data Wrapper(FDW in Postgres that points at the Oracle database. "_.   Or, conversely, a database link in the oracle database, that points to the Postgres.  Can't say one is better than the other.  Probaby comes down to personal preference.  FWIW, in oracle a db link is for connecting to _any_ other database outside of the one running the query ... that 'other' database can be oracle or something else.

Comment: Thank you, for suggesting FDW. How do we implement this in a python application and consume from cx_Oracle and psycopg2 connections

Comment: You don't. Using a `FDW` means the Oracle table is now linked to in the Postgres database. You would then just query the Postgres database. If you use @EdStevens suggestion then it would be the other way around.

Comment: BTW, I have an article on configuring the db link and oracle gateway for connection _from_ an oracle database _to_ a non-oracle database.  Once the link is correctly configured, you query it from within the oracle database with a reference to the db link, like this:    SELECT * FROM OTHER_TABLE@DB_LINK;    You can even join a local table to a table at the db link.

Comment: I forgot to give a link to the article on  link and gateway config.  See https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/